# Bar chart with PGFPlots: Two groups with two categories and two bars each

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

Using `\pgfplots`, I have a bar chart that looks like this:
[image]

Instead, I would like to have something like this, so that I have two groups ("Freie Wiedergabe Tag 1" and "Freie Wiedergabe Tag 2") in 2 categories ("Erinnert" and "Nicht erinnert") and with two bars ("neutral" and "negativ") each. I have no idea how to do this:

[image]

My MWE is here:

```
\documentclass{apa6}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.6,transform shape]
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
enlargelimits=0.15,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.25)},
anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ylabel={Anteil},
symbolic x coords={Freie Wiedergabe Tag 1,Freie Wiedergabe Tag 2,Treffer,Falscher Alarm},
xtick=data,
xticklabel style={text width=1.5cm,
font=\tiny,
align=center
},
]
%neutral
\addplot[blue,fill=blue!30!white,error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit,]
coordinates{(Treffer,0.8560) +-(0.01503,0.01503) (Falscher Alarm,0.1390) +-(0.01737,0.01737)(Freie Wiedergabe Tag 1,0.1481) +-(0.01067,0.01067) (Freie Wiedergabe Tag 2,0.1119) +-(0.00922,0.00922) };
%negativ
\addplot[red,fill=red!30!white,error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit,]
coordinates {(Treffer,0.9365) +- (0.00587,0.00587)(Falscher Alarm,0.1435) +- (0.01737,0.01737)(Freie Wiedergabe Tag 1,0.3247) +-(0.01695,0.01695) (Freie Wiedergabe Tag 2,0.2556) +-(0.01524,0.01524)
};
\legend{neutral,negativ}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Unterschrift}
\label{GedaechtnisBilder}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data points are probably not in the correct place, but apart from that one way of achieving that is shown below. I've changed the coordinates to numerical x-values (1,2,3,4) instead of symbolic coordinates, and set `xticklabels={Erinnert,Nicht erinnert,Erinnert,Nicht erinnert}`. So the four data points in each `\addplot` should correspond to those categories, the first two for the first day, the last two for the second day.

Then I've added two `extra x ticks={1.5,3.5}` (midway between the two groups of bars), with `extra x tick labels={Freie Wiedergabe Tag 1,Freie Wiedergabe Tag 2}`. Some vertical shifting of the ticklabels is done.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{apa6}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
% instead of scaling
width=0.6\linewidth,
ybar,
enlargelimits=0.15,
legend style={
% to save space I would place the legend inside the axis, at least with these data
  %at={(0.5,-0.2)},
  %anchor=north,
legend columns=-1},
ylabel={Anteil},
ylabel style={font=\large},
xtick=data,
% use explicit ticklabels instead of symbolc x coords
xticklabels={Erinnert,Nicht erinnert,Erinnert,Nicht erinnert},
xticklabel style={
%  text width=2cm,
  yshift=-18pt, % move xticks down a bit
%  align=center
},
% extra ticks
extra x ticks={1.5,3.5},
extra x tick labels={Freie Wiedergabe Tag 1,Freie Wiedergabe Tag 2},
extra x tick style={
  % because the xticklabel style also affects the extra ticks, 
  % shift extra ticklabels back up
  ticklabel style={yshift=13pt},
  % tickwidth is actually the length of of the ticks (the small lines)
  tickwidth=0
}
]
%neutral
\addplot[blue,fill=blue!30!white,error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit,]
coordinates{
   (1,0.8560) +-(0.01503,0.01503)
   (2,0.1390) +-(0.01737,0.01737)
   (3,0.1481) +-(0.01067,0.01067)
   (4,0.1119) +-(0.00922,0.00922)
};
%negativ
\addplot[red,fill=red!30!white,error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit,]
coordinates {
  (1,0.9365) +- (0.00587,0.00587)
  (2,0.1435) +- (0.01737,0.01737)
  (3,0.3247) +-(0.01695,0.01695)
  (4,0.2556) +-(0.01524,0.01524)
};
\legend{neutral,negativ}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Unterschrift}
\label{GedaechtnisBilder}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's great, thank you so much for the code and the explanations! It looks just the way I wanted it to look. Do you know a way to move the caption down a bit so that it's not too close to the "Erinnert"/"Nicht erinnert"?

Comment: @AnneB. Well, that is how captions are set in the `apa6` class, very close to the image/diagram above it. Easy fix: add `\medskip` between `\end{tikzpicture}` and `\caption`.